# Confused over hue, saturation,luminosity

Tags: color, color-theory, terminology, saturation

I am trying to make sense of luminosity, hue, saturation and color.
I read this online: Hue, saturation and value together make a color.
But hue is also the term for pure colors like red, green, violet etc.
I guess my questions would be: which one is it?
and
is luminosity same as brightness? and also called value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My understanding is that color determines the base color being worked with. If the other values are normal, color would be the difference between red and blue(for example.) Hue saturation determines how intense the color is, so having low hue saturation would make the color more grey and muted, while high hue saturation makes the color more vibrant (but not any lighter or darker) luminosity(which is the same as brightness and value) establishes how light or dark the color is.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the perfect answer I've been looking for!

Comment: No problem. This site has a lot of really great information once you get used to the question format requirements. Stop by again if you have more questions. Also, check out the answer to the linked question, it's​more in depth than my answer, but you might learn something new.